# Debugging React CSS Transitions

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm frequently getting the following warning from React in my console, which is causing some unexplainable animation bugs.

[image: React CSS Warning]

I've checked the following usual suspects:

- All children of a `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` element have `key` attributes set.
- All `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` elements have `transitionName` properties set.
- All `transitionName`s have applicable `.example-enter`, `.example-enter-active`, `.example-leave`, and `.example-leave-active` classes set with animations lasting less than 5000ms.
- All `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` elements are mounted before modifying their children.

Is there anyway to debug this? I've got  a relatively large application and React isn't really leading me anywhere to see which DOM element is triggering the warning, or what the transition name is, or basically anything useful.

**Update:**
[`TimeoutTransitionGroup`](https://github.com/Khan/react-components/blob/master/js/timeout-transition-group.jsx) has much better warning messages, like this:

[image: TimeoutTransitionGroup Warning]

Comment: Are you sure you're adding and removing the *children* of ReactCSSTransitionGroup? If you add and remove the ReactCSSTransitionGroup itself, it won't animate.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention, I'm also making absolutely sure that the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` elements are mounted **before** modifying the children. I'm definitely modifying the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Update]**

Starting in React 0.14, the buggy browser behavior for detecting transitions has been replaced by manually specifying a timeout; [see Alex's answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005558/62082).

**[Old Answer]**

I'm not sure about the best way to track down which components are having problems, but there are currently (as of v0.13.2) [bugs in `ReactTransitionGroup`](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2549) *and* bugs in browser implementations of the `animationend`/`transitionend` events that can cause this to happen on occasion. Take a look at [issue #1326](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1326) for some helpful pointers, as well as an [alternative implementation](http://khan.github.io/react-components/#timeout-transition-group) you might try (that uses `setTimeout` instead of transition events).

Answer (score 3):

Now that v0.14 of React is out, CSSTransitionGroup now takes timeouts just like TimeoutTransitionGroup.

> Add-Ons: To improve reliability, CSSTransitionGroup will no longer listen to transition events. Instead, you should specify transition durations manually using props such as transitionEnterTimeout={500}.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning